# Strange shading and artefacts on my model

Tags: modeling, shaders, subdivision-surface, bevel

I was just wondering if anybody knew how I could fix the shading issues and the artefacts on my model in a non distractive way.

**What I have tried:**
I have tried moving around some vertices (which most of the time makes the curvature of the model uneven); combining some vertices which most of the time didn't work; I have tried moving around the modifier stack which did work on some of the artefacts; I have applied the harden normals in the bevel modifier; Its not the lattice as I have set the area in which it affects to a vertex group which is not close to where this issue is occurring; I have shaded smooth, set the auto smooth to true and the set angle to 30°.

If you have any idea on how to fix please let me know, Thanks.

[image: Artefacts and strange shading issues on my model]
[image: Wireframe view of the model]

Comment: Hello, maybe show your wireframe. Also, do you absolutely want to keep all the modifiers?

Comment: Ideally I would like to keep most of the modifiers. The wireframe looks fine from what I can see. @moonboots

Comment: Actually I think in your second screenshot the wireframe doesn't look fine... would you mind showing it without the _Subdivision Surface_ modifier enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your topology is not good, try to avoid ngons, they tend to create artifacts, for example try this topology:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort going into making a model. Re-topologized my model, and it worked! I remember also that when using a deform modifier it is best to have quads. @moonboots